# Why do some light bulbs remain on when the switch is off?

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, troubleshooting

We have a situation in our bathroom where we can’t turn the lights off fully. If the switch is on, bulbs 1&2 are on. If switched off, bulb 3 is on. We’ve taken bulb 3 out for now but would like to correct the problem. Any suggestions? Diagrams very helpful.

Comment: What sort of fixture? What sort of bulbs? What sort of switch? What sort of diagrams are you hoping for? Please revise your question to add some useful information.

Comment: You need to tell us what you've changed recently (I would suspect that bulb #3 is a new addition)...

Comment: have you tried a different bulb in socket 3? I'm curious if the one you removed was an LED, or at least a different type than the other two.

Comment: Also, does your switch actually have the words "ON" and "OFF" on it? Single pole switches indicate which toggled position is on and which is off, and would be normally used in a bathroom, unless you have two entrances. Three-way switches do not say ON or OFF. One more thing, have the lights ever worked right in the past, or has it always been this way in your experience?

Comment: Is the switch lighted? If so with LED's this could provide enough to light some LED's , electronic switches can have the same issue. Snap switches are open or closed so they don't have this issue if not lighted.